# NSTableView data source method is not firing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

I have a problem with delegate methods. One of them where the array is filled into the tableView is not firing and I don't see why.
The result is that my tableView has the expected number of lines, but they are all empty. 
I set breakpoints but it doesn´t stop there.

Any clues what I could try?

```
//This is working

- (id)init  {
   self = [super init];

   cmdListMain = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Cat", @"Dog", @"Fish", nil];   

   NSLog (@"init");


   return self;
}

//This is working

- (int) numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableView *) tv
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInTableView");
return [cmdListMain count];
}

//This one is not firing** 

- (id)cmdTableView:(NSTableView *)tv 
    objectValueForTableColumn :(NSTableColumn *)cmdTableView 
          row :(int)rowIndex
{
   NSLog(@"cmdTableView");
   NSString *v = [cmdListMain objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
   return v;
}

//This is working

-(BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *) theApp  {
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ronald, you left out some important details, like what programming language you’re using. You also left out example code — usually when you ask for help with a problem on Stack Overflow, it helps to reduce your code to the minimum possible to still demonstrate the problem, then post some of it here.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you mis-spelled this data source (not delegate) method. Change this:

```
- (id)cmdTableView:(NSTableView *)tv 
objectValueForTableColumn :(NSTableColumn *)cmdTableView 
      row :(int)rowIndex
```

to this:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv 
objectValueForTableColumn :(NSTableColumn *)column 
      row :(int)rowIndex
```